# SOAP webservice method returning different types

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

Our webservice must return different types that may have one base type with some shared properties but with otherwise different properties.

Method may look like:
CreateObject(int typeID)

and depending on the typeID a different type of object would be returned. If this was no webservice, then an IOC container would do the trick. But in our scenario, the object must be created by the service and will actually be used be another service that will then pass the object to the business layer.

We are trying to avoid a lot of mapping and if possible the object types should only be defined in one place.

What would be a good design pattern to look for in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this does the trick (of course this can be nicyified with IOC etc.), the piece I was missing is the "KnownType" attribute:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    AbstractResult GetAbstractData(int id);
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(ConcreteResult1))]
[KnownType(typeof(ConcreteResult2))]
public abstract class AbstractResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ConcreteResult1 : AbstractResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ConcreteResult2 : AbstractResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Simple example of a service method:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{

    public AbstractResult GetAbstractData(int id)
    {
        if (id == 1)
            return new ConcreteResult1() { ID = 1,  Name = "red" };
        else
            return new ConcreteResult2() { ID = 2,  Number = 123 };
    }
}
```